# how to discard the last field of the content of a file using awk command

Tags: shell

how to discard the last field using awk

list.txt file contains  data like below,

```
Ram/45/simple
Gin/Run/657/No/Sand
Ram/Hol/Sin
Tan/Tin/Bun
```

but I require output like below,

```
Ram/45
Gin/Run/657/No
Ram/Hol
Tan/Tin
```

tried the following command but it prints only the last field

```
cat list.txt |awk -F '/' '{print $(NF)}'
45
No
Hol
Tin
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} NF--' Input_file
```

OR with any `awk` try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} match($0,/.*\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple awk should work:

```sh
awk '{sub(/\/[^/]*$/, "")} 1' file

Ram/45
Gin/Run/657/No
Ram/Hol
Tan/Tin
```

Or even this simpler `sed` should also work:

```sh
sed 's~/[^/]*$~~' file

Ram/45
Gin/Run/657/No
Ram/Hol
Tan/Tin
```